# Memory problems with Safari on Monterey

Tags: safari, monterey

I am having issues with Safari where it uses up huge amounts of memory.

I am wondering if others are having the same issue and/or if there is anything I can do to fix it.

Here is a screen shot from activity monitor this morning , closing it does help, but it will come back again at some point during the day depending on how much I use Safari.

[image]

Comment: Which website is this?

Comment: Well thats the thing, it isn't. I closed down all the tabs down to just the "start page" and I have sat here and watched the memory growing , it was about 3GB a couple of minutes ago with tabs open, but it grew to over 4gb with just the start page open. and now that ive opened this page, its grown again to nearly 5GB

Comment: Well, there still could be running something triggered by one of tabs. Can you start without any tab open, and then open them one by one over time to see which one causes the memory consumption?

Comment: I closed down safari, left it closed for a bit to make sure there was no lingering processes, then opened it with just the start page open and left it for 10 minutes and it grew to over 3GB without any websites being opened.

Comment: What is on your start page?

Comment: And which extensions are you using?

Comment: Extension wise I have 1password and AdGuard. On the start page is favorites, top sites, shared with you, privacy, reading list and open tabs that are on my iPhone.

Comment: Well, I would start with an empty start page, no extensions, no tabs, and build from there step by step.